# Can you force Windows to disallow SSL in all WINHTTP and HTTPAPI system calls?

Tags: windows, poodle

Title says it all. Is there a registry setting or something that will prevent the Windows built-in libraries: WINHTTP and HTTPAPI to not support SSL3?

Comment: Yes, I'm well aware that there are programming interfaces to those libraries that allow setting a preference. I'm talking about setting the preference system wide so no program, whether I have source code or do not, can use SSL3 (unless they don't use those APIs, obviously).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both those APIs use, as far as I know, the SCHANNEL API to provide their SSL functionality. [Disable SSL 3.0 in the SCHANNEL configuration](https://serverfault.com/a/637263/7200) and any applications using those APIs shouldn't be able to do SSL 3.0 anymore. (No, I haven't actually tested this-- I'm just going on my memory about those APIs.)